# How to send SMS to a phone number from iOS App (Swift) using AWS SNS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Gurus, I have created a ARN Topic and Subscribed to SMS and could send SMS message to a phone number using AWS SNS Console. However, when I try same using Swift, I do not receive SMS. Am I missing something? Here's my code to send SMS message using Swift:

```
   let smsSend = AWSSNSPublishInput.init()
    smsSend?.phoneNumber = "+1408xyzabcd"// phone_number
    smsSend?.subject = "Test SMS Notification"
    smsSend?.message = message
    smsSend?.topicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345:XYZ"

    var attribute_values = [String: AWSSNSMessageAttributeValue]()
    let smsType = AWSSNSMessageAttributeValue.init()
    smsType?.stringValue = "Promotional"
    smsType?.dataType = "String"

    let smsSenderID = AWSSNSMessageAttributeValue.init()
    smsSenderID?.stringValue = "xyz"
    smsSenderID?.dataType = "String"

    attribute_values.updateValue(smsType!, forKey: "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType")
    attribute_values.updateValue(smsSenderID!, forKey: "AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID")
    smsSend?.messageAttributes = attribute_values
    AWSSNS.default().publish(smsSend!)
```

Not sure what am I missing?

Comment: Where is your device token from APNS ?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html

Comment: May be I didn't explain clearly, I am not trying to use iOS Push Notification. My intention is to send a SMS to a phone number from my iOS App. Since Apple doesn't allow iOS app sending SMS without user intervention, I tried using AWS SNS's SMS service to do the job.   Another note -  I could use other AWS services including SES, but not SNS.

Comment: Here's the error log: <AWSTask: 0x170479b00; completed = YES; cancelled = NO; faulted = YES; result = (null)>

Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
Failed to send Text Message

Comment: Had to remove this line of code to get it working                   smsSend?.topicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345:XYZ"